# How to recognize a Nuget reference in T4 template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, t4, visual-studio-2022

**Error Message:**

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TextTemplateNuget   E:\Dev\TextTemplateNuget\TextTemplateNuget\TextTemplate1.tt 11

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'DatabaseSchemaReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Repro:**

1. Visual Studio 2022 > Console App > Add New Item > Text Template > TextTemplate1.tt
2. Add a Nuget package and reference it in your Text1Template1.tt
3. I've chosen the well known MSFT `Sql.Data.Client` assembly/dll and the a 3rd party `DatabaseSchemaReader` Nuget Package to demonstrate the issue:

**TextTemplate1.tt**

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="DatabaseSchemaReader" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\bin\Debug\net6.0\Something.dll" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=ABC"))
{
    var dbReader = new DatabaseSchemaReader.DatabaseReader(connection);
    var schema = dbReader.ReadAll();

    foreach (var table in schema.Tables)
    {                
           foreach(var col in table.Columns)
           {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(col.DataType);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(Char.ToLowerInvariant(col.Name[0]));
            sb.Append(col.Name.Substring(1));
            sb.Append(",");
            string parameterArgs = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
#>

namespace Something.<#table.Name#>
{
   public record Add<#table.Name#>Input(<#parameterArgs#>);
}
<#
      // End of file.
      SaveOutput("Content1" + ".txt");
    }
}}
#>

<#+
private void SaveOutput(string outputFileName) {
  string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
  string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
  File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 
  this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
}
#>
```

How can I resolve these errors? The messages indicate I don't have the DLLs referenced properly, yet I've clearly added them.

**Update:**

I tried adding all the assemblies in the bin folder as references, no luck Visual Studio 2022 still doesn't detect them.

Specifying the full path to the DLLs is supposed to as per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/modeling/t4-assembly-directive?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Just a guess, but do you need a new `<#@ assembly #>` for each reference?

Answer (score 0):

To use SqlConnection in C# code you have a directive:
using System.Data.SqlClient;
in T4 you write:
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
to get the same "using" in code to which converted T4.

Simplest way to understand what you need to do - create RuntimeTextTemplate1.tt and see what is in produced code.